# Can HTML character entities in plain text emails be replaced?

Tags: bug, email, stackexchange.com, html-entities

In a recent tag filter email message, in the plain text part of the message an HTML entity for the horizontal ellipsis appeared at the end of the question preview:

```
I'm trying to just read the exif and xmp of a jpg with PHP. I've tried
several options, including the Metadata toolkit from ozhiker, which will
never load (It just says that there's no specified file, &hellip;
```

The [original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20405982/getting-xmp-and-exif-from-jpg-with-php) has no ellipsis at that point in the text.

Since the character set used is UTF-8, can `&hellip;` be replaced by `…` *U+2026 HORIZONTAL ELLIPSIS*?

Edit: punctuation varies within emails.

In a new tag filter, the first email I received has `...` instead of `&hellip;`:

```
I'm creating a visual editor Web app using Spring MVC. The visualizaton
has some properties: public class VisualizationProperties { double
strokeWidth = 1; Rectangle selectedArea; } ...
```

Again, the [original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20435448/spring-mvc-scoped-controller-using-class-based-proxy-there-is-already-scopedt) has no punctuation at that point in the text. But the output punctuation is different.

Another question in the same email has `&hellip;` again:

```
I'm looking for a way to make it so that when the user switches tabs the
contextual action bar that I have becomes invalid. I have it set up so
that the tabs are linked to Fragments and each one &hellip;
```

[Original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20435334/invalidate-contextual-action-bar-on-when-switching-tabs)

Comment: You know, [the font ellipsis pretty much never looks as good as spaced dots do](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/91654). It’s way too compressed. ’Twould be better to just space them out normally.

Comment: @tchrist thanks for the pointer to the discussion. I'm not opposing other replacements, but I'm also thinking "don't change the content because others make it look bad; this is a font problem, not my problem". Also, in text/plain mode, many email clients use a fixed width font, which makes three dots pretty wide (I think). Nevermind though, I'd just like to do away with HTML relics in text/plain :)